Taylor expansion of composite mapping
I'm trying to understand the derivation of equation 7 in this paper.
$\Phi_\theta^{AB}(x)$ and $\Phi_\theta^{BA}(x): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ are maps from the coordinate space of Image A to Image B and vice versa. These maps are perturbed by a small ($\epsilon > 0$) amount of white noise ($n_1$, $n_2$) with mean 0 and variance 1.
$$
\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB}(x) = \Phi_\theta^{AB}(x) + \epsilon n_1(\Phi_\theta^{AB}(x))
$$
$$
\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}(x) = \Phi_\theta^{BA}(x) + \epsilon n_2(\Phi_\theta^{BA}(x))
$$
To encourage approximate inverse consistency between the maps, they seek to minimise the following norm:
$$
\lVert \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA} - I_d \rVert_2^2
$$
where $I_d$ is the identity mapping.
They then proceed to linearise the composite map ($\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}$) about the point $\epsilon = 0$ to obtain the following equation:
$$
\lVert \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA} - Id \rVert_2^2 \approx \lVert \Phi_{\theta}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta}^{BA} + \epsilon n_1(\Phi_{\theta}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta}^{BA}) + d{\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB}}(\epsilon n_2(\Phi_\theta^{BA})) - I_d \rVert_2^2 
$$
where $d{\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB}}$ is the Jacobian of $\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB}$.
I have attempted the derivation below:
$$
F(x, \epsilon) = \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}
$$
$$
= \Phi_\theta^{AB}(\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}) + \epsilon n_1(\Phi_\theta^{AB}(\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}))
$$
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta\epsilon}(x, \epsilon) = \frac{d\Phi_\theta^{AB}}{dx} \bigg\rvert_{x=\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}}\frac{\delta \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA}}{\delta \epsilon} + n_1(\Phi_\theta^{AB}(\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA})) + \epsilon...
$$
where $\epsilon...$ is a term that will be very small in the linearisation due to $\epsilon ^ 2$ and is presumably discounted.
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta\epsilon}\bigg\rvert_{\epsilon = 0} = \frac{d\Phi_\theta^{AB}}{dx} \bigg\rvert_{x=\Phi_{\theta}^{BA}}\epsilon n_2(\Phi_\theta^{BA}(x)) + n_1(\Phi_\theta^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta}^{BA})
$$
Using the derivative, the linearisation about $\epsilon = 0$ would be:
$$
\lVert \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{BA} - Id \rVert_2^2 \approx \lVert \Phi_{\theta}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta}^{BA} + \epsilon n_1(\Phi_{\theta}^{AB} \circ \Phi_{\theta}^{BA}) + \frac{d\Phi_\theta^{AB}}{dx} \bigg\rvert_{x=\Phi_{\theta}^{BA}}\epsilon n_2(\Phi_\theta^{BA}(x)) - I_d \rVert_2^2 
$$
The only differences are in the Jacobian term. Their linearisation has $d{\Phi_{\theta\epsilon}^{AB}}$, but since the derivative is evaluated at $\epsilon = 0$, should this be $d{\Phi_{\theta}^{AB}}$? Also they have that the Jacobian is evaluated at $\epsilon n_2(\Phi_\theta^{BA})$, but shouldn't this be multiplied by the Jacobian evaluated at $\Phi_\theta^{BA}$?
Any ideas what I'm missing here?
